# Trying to convert a Float64 into Float32 on ROS

Tags: ros, floating-point-conversion

i'm working on a project on ROS, i'm trying to pass from a visualization of a marker into a visualization of a point in a pointcloud.

the markers coordinates are rappresented in float64

the points (of pcl) coordinates are rappresented in float32

i use a simil c++ for implementing code.

i want simply to try if i'm going to lose a lot of precision in terms of performance with this type of conversion.
but don't know how to do it.

did someone could help me with a piece of code that make this conversion?

thanks!

Comment: What exactly do you want to convert? Casting between `float32` and `float64` should work automatically as they are just typedefs for `float` and `double`.

Comment: i want to convert the float64 in a float32, but don't know how write the code, and don't find it in the web too...
probably i'm too busy and stressed to link my brain on that...
and asked here an help...
maybe there are some function even in ROS that i could call for make the conversion possible...

Comment: i'd solve it, thank you anyway, you put me on the right way ^^